# The infamous sub(s,c,d)

Tags: logic, incompleteness, meta-math

Given the following godel coding scheme:

$$\langle a_0,a_1,\ldots,a_{k-1}\rangle\implies 2^k 3^{a_0} 5^{a_1}\cdots\pi(k)^{a_{k-1}}$$

$ \\ $

How does one show that the function $sub(s,c,d)$ that replaces any appearance of the number c in the sequence coded by s with the number d is primitive recursive??

Answer (score 0):

Note: Most of these are from Boolos' "Computability and Logic". It is going to be strongly assumed here that one is familiar with properties of recursive functions and relations. I will define these functions and leave it to the reader to verify they are recursive:

$ \\ $

**quo(x,y) to be the quotient of x by y**

$$quo(x,y):=
\begin{cases}
 (\xi\ z \leq x) & y*z \leq x & ,y \neq 0 \\
\\
0 & & ,y = 0
\end{cases}
$$

$(\xi\ $ here means the greatest$)$

$\\$

**lo(x,y) the highest exponent of y dividing x(in practice, the exponent of y in prime factorization of x**

$$lo(x,y):=
\begin{cases}
 (\xi\ z \leq x) & y^z |\, x & x,y>1 \\
\\
0 & & else
\end{cases}
$$

$ \\ $

**lh(s): length of sequence encoded by s**

$$lh(s):= lo(s,2)$$

$ \\ $

**ent(s,i): The ith entry in the sequence coded by s**

$$ent(s,i) = lo(s,\pi(i+1))$$

$ \\ $

**Recursive definition of y divides x**

$$y|x \iff \big(\exists z \leq x\big)\ x= y*z$$

$ \\ $

**Recursive definition of prime number**

$$Prime(y) \iff \ y > 1 \quad \land \quad \big(\forall z \leq y\big)\big(\ z\,|\, y \implies z = y \lor z = 1\big)$$

$ \\ $

**nPr(x) the next prime after x (mu means least here)**

$$nPr(x):=\big(\mu y \leq x!+1\big)(x < y \ \land \ Prime(y)\big) $$

$ \\ $

**PI(n): the nth prime counting 2 as the 0th**

$$\pi(0):= 2, \quad \pi(n+1):= nPr(n)$$

$ \\ $

**fst(s): 1st (really 0th) entry in the sequence coded by s**

$$fst(s):= ent(s,0)$$

**sub(s,c,d): sequence obtained by substituting occurrences of c for d in sequence coded by s.**

Here we use course of values recursion, have to define an auxiliary function:

$$sub(s,c,d,0):=s$$

$ \\ $

$$
sub(s,c,d,i+1):=
\begin{cases}
sub(s,c,d,i) & \quad ent(s,i) \neq c \\
\\
quo\bigg(sub(s,c,d,i),nPr(\pi(i))^c\bigg)*nPr(\pi(i))^d & \quad ent(s,i) = c
\end{cases}
$$

and finally $$sub(s,c,d):= sub(s,c,d,lh(s))$$

Comment: Sorry but why do you care of those implementation details ?

Comment: @reuns I actually put this up here for a friend I was helping through it in chat. That being said, are you asking me what the point of all of this is?

Comment: I would show instead how any programming language can be encoded in the axiomatic theory, or in a recursive function, by encoding the sequence of states of the program as a sequence of binary represented integers.